# Plot does not plot over the specified range

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have these two sets of data:

```
data1 = {{0, 0}, {5, 0}, {10, .1}, {15, .3}, {20, .7}, {25, 1}, {30, 1}};
data2 = {{0, 0}, {5, 0}, {10, 0}, {15, 0}, {20, 0}, {25, .1}, {30, .3}};
```

and I fit them with a cumulative Gaussian function:

```
cumulativeGauss[x_, μ_, Σ_] := 
    CDF[NormalDistribution[μ, Σ], x]
```

I obtain the parameters that I'll use to plot these functions:

```
fit1 = FindFit[
    data1, cumulativeGauss[x, μ, Σ],
    {{μ, 5}, {Σ, 5}}, x][[All, 2]];
fit2 = FindFit[
    data2, cumulativeGauss[x, μ, Σ],
    {{μ, 5}, {Σ, 5}}, x][[All, 2]];
```

Here below are all the plots that I've produced to show the problem.
The left column shows that when only the `Plot` command is used the function is plotted along the whole range, so no problem. On the other hand, the right column shows the figures produced by combining a `ListPlot` with a `Plot`. The first figure shows no problem, however, the figure in the second row does not plot the function along the whole range. This problem can be solved by increasing the range over which the function is plotted (figure in the 3rd row). Any hint about why this problem occurs and/or if there is any other solution?

[image]

Here the the code to generate the figures:

```
GraphicsGrid[
    {
        {
        Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit1[[1]], fit1[[2]]], {x, 0, 30},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
        Show[ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
            Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit1[[1]], fit1[[2]]], {x, 0, 30}]]
        },

        {
        Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
        Show[ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
            Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30}]]
        },
        {
        Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
        Show[ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
            Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 40}]]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: In the second row you didn't set the same plot range in `Plot` in the `Show` as before, this is what causes the cutoff.  Don't use `PlotRange` in `ListPlot`, but do use it in `Plot`.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your comment on the plot range in the second row. The first two rows have the same plot ranges, but only in the first row the function is plotted correctly.

Comment: I mean, do include the PlotRange specification in Plot as well, not only in ListPlot.  Actually their order in Show doesn't matter.  I'm sorry if I'm not clear, I'm a bit sleep deprived.

Comment: Yes, I agree, your suggestion certainly solves the issue. I was however convinced that the first function in `Show` _always_ controls the graphics settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to use the same `PlotRange` for cell (2,2) as for the other cells.

You can change the order: show `Plot` before `ListPlot`.  Note that `Plot` will now set the `PlotRange`; as I understand it, the first function called by `Show` controls the graphics settings (if there should be a conflict).

```
Show[Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30},  
           PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
     ListPlot[data2]
    ]
```

The following questions remain:

- "Why isn't the full plot range displayed when `ListPlot` comes before `Plot`?
- "Why can't you specify the `PlotRange` in `Show` as follows?"

  `Show[Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30}],
        ListPlot[data2], PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}]`
   According to the [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrlzh.png), this latter approach should work  (but it does not):

[image: instruction]

Either of these result in the following:

[image: PlotRange2]

---

**Edit**

You can display the data points beneath the model using. Note, however that the points will lie beneath the axes.

```
Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30},  
     PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}},
     PlotRangePadding -> {{.3, 3}, {0.1, 0}},
     Prolog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[data2]}]
```

[image: points shown]

Comment: I was aware that changing the order of `Plot` and `ListPlot`solves the problem, but I bumped in this problem because I prefer to plot the fitted function over the data and not the other way around. Why the options specified in `Show` do not override those included in the graphics expression is thus still a mystery.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that

```
Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30}]
```

> [image]

is clipping where it goes off the top of the vertical plot range.
Forcing that plot to `PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}` like the others will solve the problem:

```
GraphicsGrid[
    {
        {
        Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit1[[1]], fit1[[2]]], {x, 0, 30},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
        Show[ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
            Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit1[[1]], fit1[[2]]], {x, 0, 30}]]
        },

        {
        Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
        Show[ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
            Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30}, 
                 PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}]]
        },
        {
        Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 30},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
        Show[ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}],
            Plot[cumulativeGauss[x, fit2[[1]], fit2[[2]]], {x, 0, 40}]]
        }
    }
]
```

> [image]

Comment: Now I know at least why the cutoff occurs at that specific location. However, being forced to use multiple definitions of the plot range might be slightly unhandy in certain instances.

Comment: `{p = Plot[...], Show[ListPlot[...], p]}` should work.  Or creating a function that takes `data` and `fit` and constructs each row.  With the latter, it's then very easy to set options for all the plots.